# System Rules not finding emptyStandardInputStream(); method

Tags: junit, system-rules

The std coding example shows the emptyStandardInputStream() method. But the compiler can't resolve it.

```
@Rule
public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();
```

1. Rule - yep, got that.
2. TextFromStandardInputStream  - yep, got that.
3. emptyStandardInputStream() - nope, doesn't compile.

Any ideas? 
Thanks
-Simon

Comment: What "std coding example"? Can you provide a link?

Comment: How about `TextFromStandardInputStream.emptyStandardInputStream()`?

Comment: Did you use 
import static org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.TextFromStandardInputStream.*;

Answer (score 1):

Compiler unable to locate emptyStandardInputStream() method.
As this is a static method, you can use TextFromStandardInputStream class to explicitly locate the method.

```
@Rule
public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = 
                                    TextFromStandardInputStream.emptyStandardInputStream();
```